# How can I fix a false positive in the Broken Links report?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have some item content that is working just fine... but shows up as a broken link in the Broken Links Report.  The link in question is in a Rich Text field:

```
<img style="WIDTH: 700px; HEIGHT: 1029px" class="imageBG" alt="All Alaska Map" src="~/media/Images/NorthToAlaska/maps/allAlaskaRouteFLNew.jpg?w=700&amp;h=1029&amp;as=1" />
```

If I use the built-in editor and insert an image, it generates a link like this:

```
<img width="700" height="1029" alt="All Alaska Route Map" src="~/media/F82D13579F3A4D0E88C4436D84A562F8.jpg?w=700&amp;h=1029&amp;as=1" />
```

I should note, that even using the "Insert Media Item" button, it shows up as a broken link.  :(

In general, I'd much rather have the image path referenced than an item GUID that is impossible to identify if I'm just looking at it.

1) Why does that first link show up as broken, even though it works fine on the site? 
 
2) Is there any way to get the editor to insert media item links with paths instead of GUIDs? 
3) Alternately, is there a way to modify the way broken links are detected or reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej Bryan

1: Did you try to rebuild the Link Database?
To rebuild the Link Database you just have to open the Control Panel and go to the Database point. There will be an option where you can rebuild the Link Database.

2: I'm asuming you are meaning the rich text editor. It's on purpose that it inserts IDs instead of paths. If Sitecore would use paths it couldn't detect if you move the target item elsewhere in the tree. To get friendly URLs out of that you need to use the right controls of Sitecore. In XSL for example `sc:fld` won't render friendly URLs use `sc:field` instead.

3: In what way do you want to modify it? A custom report?

Comment: Thanks halbherz, turns out the editor-inserted link does NOT show up after re-running the report.  I was just looking at the results of validation warning.  Still annoying that a valid link to a valid item shows up in the report, but evidently there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: The validator even shows up if there are xhtml errors in the markup of the field. You can remove or add those validators here: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types`